# Task in Click event does not handle UI related changes wpf

Tags: wpf, user-interface, buttonclick

I have a button that has a complex API call. So I put that portion of code in Task Factory. I set the visibility of Progress Bar accordingly. But on the click, the progress bar doesnt get visible. Dont know where I am going wrong!

```
private RelayCommand<string> _selectGenderCommand;

public RelayCommand<string> SelectGenderCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _selectGenderCommand
            ?? (_selectGenderCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(
         p =>
          {
             ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
              Utilities utility = new Utilities();
              Task tskOpen = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
              {
                  if (p.Equals(Constants.GenderMale))
                  {
                      App.PatientMatchGender = Constants.GenderMale;
                  }
                  else if (p.Equals(Constants.GenderFemale))
                  {
                      App.PatientMatchGender = Constants.GenderFemale;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      App.PatientMatchGender = Constants.GenderInterSex;
                  }

                  utility.MatchPatient(App.PatientMatchGender);

              }
            ).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => utility.PatientMatchForwardNavigation()));
                ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
          }));
    }
}
```

Why does the progress bar not show up? UI thread should be working right?

Comment: Are you following the MVVM concept?

Comment: Please post your `ProgressBar` bindings (XAML). If you're using .NET 4.5+, then I suggest you to start new tasks via `Task.Run()` rather than `Task.Factory.StartNew()`.

Comment: I doubt that using `Task` has anything to do with it. Most likely culprit is faulty binding - either wrong path (check output in debug mode for errors) or improper/lack of `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation/usage.

Comment: ProgressBarVisibility property is set like this: `private Visibility _progressBarVisibility;

        public Visibility ProgressBarVisibility
        {
            get { return _progressBarVisibility; }
            set { _progressBarVisibility = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => ProgressBarVisibility); }
        }`

Comment: @Grx70 and @dymanoid :  The progress bar is a customized one which is a user control. It is referred in the xaml like this: ` <Viewbox Width="50" Height="50"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            <local:ProgressBarUC x:Name="ProgressBar" Visibility="{Binding ProgressBarVisibility}"/>
        </Viewbox>`

Comment: Did you find any useful info in the output? Look for lines beginning with `System.Windows.Data Error`. If not, there are several tricks you could do to debug the problem. First of all, put a breakpoint at the line where progress bar visibility is set to visible and assure that it is hit and that the property is successfully set. Moreover, I can see that you are using custom progress bar (I assume it derives from `ProgressBar`) - perhaps you're setting the visibility in code somewhere (not by binding)?